# Are there quran that are written before othman standardization?

Tags: quran

Uthman create a standard of quran. Before that there are many versions of Quran. Are there any of those other versions that survive now?

Comment: You say there are many versions of Quran before Uthman and you ask are there any other version that survive now? There is a big contradiction here.

Comment: @hellzone You missed the "Before that". And @ OP "Before that there are many versions of Quran." needs reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lower text of the [Sana'a manuscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sana%27a_manuscript) is, as far as I know, the [only existing example of pre-Uthmanic Qur'an](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/islm.2010.87.issue-1-2/islam-2011-0025/islam-2011-0025.xml) available today.  Uthman's text was standardized very early in Islamic history; every live copy, and pretty much every historical manuscript, we have to date is based on the Uthmanic tradition.