# Is there any physically written first Quran book?

Tags: quran

I'm not Muslim. And I'm searching the answer for the first documented Quran book. Still couldn't get a certain answer. Some of my Muslim friends says it was first given to the followers. Then they memorize it and teach to the next generation. Later only which was documented in book.

Is there any first Quran book in written form?

And who was documenting the first Quran book?

Are they having the very first book as reference?

Simply I'm not referring oldest book discovered. I want to know, in history who was doing the work of writing it to a book?

Comment: Well you should check [Are there any actual textual differences in quran?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/are-there-any-actual-textual-differences-in-quran?) , [Are there quran that are written before Othman standardization?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10620/are-there-quran-that-are-written-before-othman-standardization?) and [Prophet Muhammad saw was illiterate who wrote the quran then?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28370/prophet-muhammad-saw-was-illiterate-who-wrote-the-quran-then/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quran with original manuscript evidence](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/22901/quran-with-original-manuscript-evidence) and others posted in the above comment. You can request for clarification in the fore mentioned links.

Answer (score 1):

According to the last research the oldest Quran is located in UK.

"What may be the world's oldest fragments of the Koran have been found by the University of Birmingham.
Radiocarbon dating found the manuscript to be at least 1,370 years old, making it among the earliest in existence."

Prof Thomas: "These portions must have been in a form that is very close to the form of the Koran read today, supporting the view that the text has undergone little or no alteration and that it can be dated to a point very close to the time it was believed to be revealed."

[Oldest Quran in UK belongs to](http://www.bbc.com/news/business-33436021)

Comment: That is an important information. But which one is used as the reference in case if they identify deviation between currently printed books?

Comment: That (linked) document can hardly be the oldest Quran, as it clearly shows that it has been written during the period of the Omayyad dynasty (points as a first helping tool for the pronunciation) and it's well known that at least two older copies still exist (Egypt,Turkey).

Comment: @Medi1Saif: The parchment of the Birmingham leaves was radio-carbon dated to between AD 568 and 645, within a 95.4% (2σ) confidence interval. Do you have references for, or links to, radio-carbon dated older copies?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick no, but here a critical article about the radio-carbon method http://www.fantomzeit.de/?p=4080#more-4080 where archeological coprus of finds of the Middle ages (15th. 16th Century) have been dated to be from >3000 BC